# Rails - compressing CSV files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compression

I'm trying to attach a zipped CSV file to an e-mail without any joy. I've tried following http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Gzip.html:

```
class UserExportProcessor

 @queue = :user_export_queue

  def self.perform(person_id, collection_ids)
    person = Person.unscoped.find(person_id)
    collection = Person.unscoped.where(id: [49522, 70789])
    file = ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(collection.to_csv)
    PersonMailer.people_export(person, file).deliver
  end
end
```

This sends an attachment - still as a CSV file - filled with symbols (no letters or numbers).

When I try and remove the compression:

```
class UserExportProcessor

 @queue = :user_export_queue

  def self.perform(person_id, collection_ids)
    person = Person.unscoped.find(person_id)
    collection = Person.unscoped.where(id: [49522, 70789])
    PersonMailer.people_export(person, collection.to_csv).deliver
  end
end
```

The system e-mails the CSV file as it should and the CSV is properly formed. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to make a new file out of the compressed data? I've tried various approaches with no joy..

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm trying

```
class UserExportProcessor
  require 'zip'

  @queue = :user_export_queue

  def self.perform(person_id, collection_ids)
    person = Person.unscoped.find(person_id)
    collection = Person.unscoped.where(id: [49522, 70789])
    file = Zip::ZipFile.open("files.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) { |zipfile|
      puts zipfile.get_output_stream(collection.to_csv)
      zipfile.mkdir("a_dir")
    end
    PersonMailer.people_export(person, file).deliver
  end
end
```

However this fails with:

```
Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: File name too long - /Users/mark/projects/bla/Role,Title,First Name,Last Name,Address 1,Address 2,Address 3,City,Postcode,Country,Email,Telephone,Mobile,Job Title,Company,Area of work,Department,Regions,Account Manager,Sales Coordinator,Production Studios,Production Partners,Genres,Last login,Created date
```

Is there any way for me to set the file name with the above approach?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake probably happens in the code of PersonMailer.people_export (which you didn't include). So this is my best guess: you probably add the attachment and do not properly define the mime-type.

Make sure you set the correct file extension when you add the attachment:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#adding-attachments

something along this line should work:

```
attachments['archive.zip'] = ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(collection.to_csv)
```